# WPF Adding Path to ContentControl Doesn't Work At Runtime

Tags: c#, wpf

Hi have a program that will add any object to canvas at runtime. I'm using ContentControl per requirement. ContentControl will be attached to drag, resize and rotate that's why we cannot use other object. The items will be added at runtime and all controls created will be added on canvas at the end. The code below simply adds two objects an ellipse and a geometry. The ellipse is showing in the canvas but not the geometry. However if added in the XAML directly it is showing. If in code behind adding Path directly as child of canvas it is also working. Please help. How to show this geometry shape via code behind at runtime when added to ContentControl.

**DOESN'T WORK**

C#

```
  public partial class Window1 : Window
    {
        
        public Window1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            AddItemsToCanvas();
        }

        void AddItemsToCanvas()
        {
            //add Ellipse
            var contentControl = new ContentControl();
            contentControl.Width = 130;
            contentControl.Height = 130;
            contentControl.MinHeight = 5;
            contentControl.MinWidth = 5;
            Canvas.SetTop(contentControl, 50);
            Canvas.SetLeft(contentControl, 100);
            var ellipse = new Ellipse { Fill = Brushes.Blue, Stretch = Stretch.Fill, IsHitTestVisible = false };
            var border = new Border { Background = Brushes.Transparent, VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Stretch, HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Stretch };
            border.Child = ellipse;
            contentControl.Content = border;
            canvas.Children.Add(contentControl);

            //add geometry. This doesn't work.
            var contentGeomControl = new ContentControl();
            contentGeomControl.Width = 130;
            contentGeomControl.Height = 130;
            contentGeomControl.MinHeight = 5;
            contentGeomControl.MinWidth = 5;
            Canvas.SetTop(contentGeomControl, 50);
            Canvas.SetLeft(contentGeomControl, 100);
            var streamGeometry = StreamGeometry.Parse("M150,300 L300,300 A150,150 0 0 0 256,194 z");
            var path = new Path { Data = streamGeometry, Fill = Brushes.Wheat, IsHitTestVisible = false };
            var borderGeom = new Border { Background = Brushes.Transparent, VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Stretch, HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Stretch };
            borderGeom.Child = path;
            contentGeomControl.Content = borderGeom;
            canvas.Children.Add(contentGeomControl);
        }
    }
}
```

XAML

```
<Window x:Class="DiagramDesigner.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
    Title="Move, resize and rotate"
    Height="550" Width="750" Name="Win1">
<Window.Resources>
 <Canvas Name="canvas" Background="White" Opacity="99">
    
</Canvas>
```

**THIS WORKS BUT WE NEED ADDING ITEMS AT RUNTIME**

```
XAML
```

```
<Canvas Name="canvas" Background="White" Opacity="99">
    <ContentControl>
        <ContentControl.Content>
            <Border >
                <Path Fill="Wheat" Data="M150,300 L300,300 A150,150 0 0 0 256,194 z"/>
            </Border>
        </ContentControl.Content>
    </ContentControl>
</Canvas>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting the `Width`, `Height`, `MinHeight`, `MinWidth`, `Canvas.Top` and `Canvas.Left` properties in your code but not in your XAML. That's the difference. Try to remove these lines:

```
var contentGeomControl = new ContentControl();
var streamGeometry = StreamGeometry.Parse("M150,300 L300,300 A150,150 0 0 0 256,194 z");
var path = new Path { Data = streamGeometry, Fill = Brushes.Wheat, IsHitTestVisible = false };
var borderGeom = new Border { Background = Brushes.Transparent, VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Stretch, HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Stretch };
borderGeom.Child = path;
contentGeomControl.Content = borderGeom;
canvas.Children.Add(contentGeomControl);
```

Then you should see the same results.

Comment: Thank you so much! I've been figuring out what's the problem for hours.